# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;) with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

I am learning selenium with eclipse. I have added required external .jar files but still getting the error while executing the test case.

[image: Error image]

Comment: have you tried adding `chromedriver.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `chromedriver.exe`.

Just add the path to your chrome driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

You can see an example [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when also having the maven surefire plugin in the pom file. After removing that dependencies, the chrome driver run fine.